# ¿Cómo guardar imagenes temporales y mostrarlas en un div en HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

De hecho no estoy muy seguro de que si lo que pregunto es exactamente lo que necesito, lo cual es seleccionar varias imagenes que se guarden temporalmente dentro de la carpeta de mi servidor y luego oprimir un boton para almacenarlas permanentemente.

Lo que quiero hacer poder visualizarlas para luego guardarlas, obteniendo su nombre.

Hasta ahora no tengo nada de codigo avanzado porque estoy perdido.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Vista Previa</title>
 </head>

 <body>
  <center>
   <input type="file" name="archivo" id="imagen">
   <button id="guardar">Guardar</button>

   <div id="preview">
    <!-- Lugar donde se mostraran las imagenes -->
   </div>
  </center>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una opción sería recurrir a la Interface [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/URL) , específicamente a su método [createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) para representar el objeto `File` que se recibe en el `input`

```js
$(document).on('change','#imagen',function(){
 if(this.files && this.files[0]){
    /* Creamos la Imagen*/
  var img = $('<img >');
    /* Asignamos el atributo source , haciendo uso del método createObjectURL*/
  img.attr('src', URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]));
    /* Añadimos al Div*/
   $('#preview').append(img);
 }
});
```

```css
img{
 width: 100PX;
 height: 100px;
 margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="archivo" id="imagen">

<div id="preview">

</div>
```

Comment: Amigo eso me fue enserio de gran ayuda, sabes como guardar esa imagen temporal que se carga?, me genera un url como este blob:http://localhost/183214a8-5211-47bb-b6a7-c146761bf514. Necesito guardarla en la misma carpeta de mi index.

Answer (score 0):

Para visualizarlas podés usar html5 [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FileReader).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#imagen").on("change", function() {
    if(typeof(FileReader) != undefined){
      var preview = $("#preview");
      preview.empty();

      var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e){
          $("#preview").attr("src", e.target.result);
        }

      reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[0]);
    }else{
      console.log("Formato desconocido");
    }
    
  });
});
```

```css
#preview {
  display:block;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="imagen" name="imagen" required="">
<img id="preview">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es poder tener ciertas imagenes guardadas temporalmente y luego tomar una decisión si guardarlas o no en tu servidor lo mejor sería que las guardes en la computadora del cliente.

Existen ciertas alternativas para hacer esto:

- Cookies
- localStorage

Si te decides por localStorage necesitas almacenar el base64 puesto que no es posible la imagen como tal, te quedaría algo así la funcion para tener el base 64:

```
function getBase64Image(img) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}
```

y para almacenar en el localstorage

```
imgData = getBase64Image(bannerImage);
localStorage.setItem("imgData", imgData);
```

Esas imagenes las puedes listar en la computadora del cliente y luego las que seleccione las subes a tu servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Con el siguiente código podrás seleccionar múltiples imagines que serán mostradas en **tags img** independientes con **ids** diferentes para que puedas trabajarlas después.

```js
function muestraImg() {
  var contenedor = document.getElementById("muestrasImg");
  var archivos = document.getElementById("cargarImg").files;
  for (i = 0; i < archivos.length; i++) {
    imgTag = document.createElement("img");
    imgTag.height = 200;//ESTAS LINEAS NO SON "NECESARIAS" 
    imgTag.width = 400; //ÚNICAMENTE HACEN QUE LAS IMÁGENES SE VEAN 
    imgTag.id = i;      // ORDENADAS CON UN TAMAÑO ESTÁNDAR
    imgTag.src = URL.createObjectURL(archivos[i]);
    contenedor.appendChild(imgTag);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="file" id="cargarImg" onchange="muestraImg()" multiple>
  <div id="muestrasImg"> </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Espero que te ayude.
saludos.